# Order of precedence in calculator grammar

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I am beginning to study ANTLR and currently going thru "Definitive ANTLR4" reference and was wondering why in the calculator example order of precedence works? The grammar used is:

```
grammar LabeledExpr; 

prog:   stat+ ;

stat:   expr NEWLINE                # printExpr
    |   ID '=' expr NEWLINE         # assign
    |   NEWLINE                     # blank
    |   CLEAR                       # clearMemory
    ;

expr:   expr op=('*'|'/') expr      # MulDiv
    |   expr op=('+'|'-') expr      # AddSub
    |   INT                         # int
    |   ID                          # id
    |   '(' expr ')'                # parens
    ;

CLEAR: 'clear';

MUL :   '*' ; // assigns token name to '*' used above in grammar
DIV :   '/' ;

ADD :   '+' ;
SUB :   '-' ;

ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;      // match identifiers
INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

2 + 2 * 2 produces this tree and 6

[image]

Why doesn't it calculate addition first? I mean it's correct, I just don't know why.

Comment: 8? You mean 6, right?

Comment: @BartKiers Doh. Of course 6 (will fix it). I was trying to make it produce 8 and it was on my mind.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I think I got the answer (and all it took me to post the question at SO).

If I am not mistaken it's because in the parser multiplication and division are the first rule.

```
expr:   expr op=('*'|'/') expr      # MulDiv
    |   expr op=('+'|'-') expr      # AddSub
```

Comment: Correct, if you put `AddSub` before `MulDiv`, `+` and `-` will get precedence over `*` and `/`